# javascript regex allow multiple words with quotes

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a `<textarea>` where I need to validate that everything between double quotes is either latitude or longitude.  I have it set up so that the word can not be used more than 3 times which is fine. But I have an error message that shows when the wrong format is used.  I need the error to pop up when the user focuses out and hasn't put anything in between quotes or it's not latitude or longitude.

Here is my demo:

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ryanverdel/byJCG/)**

```
$('#test').on('keydown focusout', function(e){
var word  = 'latitude',
    count = this.value.match(new RegExp('"\\b'+word+'\\b"','g')) ||  [],
    limiter = $('#output');

$('#output').text(count.length);

return !(count.length > 2 && e.which != 8);

});

//Error - Max limit reached

$('#test').bind('keyup focusout', function(){  
limiter = $('#output');

if(limiter.text() == '3'){

    $('#limitReached').attr("class","hi");
    $('#limitReached').text("You cannot exeed more than 10 coorniates");
    $('#test').css({'border': '1px solid red'});

}
else{
     $('#limitReached').attr("class","bye");
     $('#limitReached').text("");
     $('#test').css({'border': '1px solid black'});
}
});

//Error - Format is wrong

$('#test').on('focusout', function(e){  
var word1  = 'latitude',
    word2  = 'longitude', 
    count = this.value.match(new RegExp('"\\b'+word1+'\\b"','g')) || [];

if ($(this).val() != count){

    $('#limitReached').attr("class","hi");
    $('#limitReached').html('Please use correct JSON format:<br> example - [{"latitude":33.851871,"longitude":-84.364336},]');
    $('#test').css({'border': '1px solid red'});

}
else{
     $('#limitReached').attr("class","bye");
     $('#limitReached').text("");
     $('#test').css({'border': '1px solid black'});
}
});
```

Comment: You're apparently trying to parse JSON with regexes - don't! Use JSON.parse in a try-catch block.

Comment: BTW, the example json you provided isn't actually valid json, it has an extra comma.

Comment: @thg435 - Could you give an example of this?

Comment: @KevinB - Thanks, I did not notice that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Referring to thg435's comment:

If you try to parse invalid json a `SyntaxError` is thrown. See the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse):

> JSON.parse parses a string as JSON and returns the parsed value.
>
> ...
>
> If the string to parse is not valid JSON, a SyntaxError exception is thrown.

Sample code:

```
try {
    var json = JSON.parse('[{"latitude":33.851871,"longitude":-84.364336}]');
    if (json.length > 3) throw new Error("Too many coordinates");
    _.each(json, function(coordinate) {
        if (!_.has(coordinate, 'latitude') || !_.has(coordinate, 'longitude')) throw new Error("Invalid coordinate pair found");
    });
}
catch (e) {
    // handle your invalid json and return to stop further execution
    console.error(e);
    return;
}

console.info('ok');
```

This approach uses [underscorejs](http://underscorejs.org/#has)

See for a working copy here: http://jsfiddle.net/fcvyL/2/

Comment: I already have a limiter. I don't need to test for the length.  I need to test if they exist in the double quotes.  I tried to put this in my fiddle under the //Error - Format is wrong | section and didn't get any results.

Comment: You want to validate that every coordinate pair has a longitude and a latitude?

Comment: Again, I tried adding that to my fiddle above and it still isn't working.  I tried alert() functions where you threw errors and didn't get anything.  I see you also have a set string.  My textarea allows users to input new coordinates so it can't be fixed.  Is there a way to combine what you have with my fiddle.
==>
[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ryanverdel/byJCG/)

Comment: Sorry added the wrong fiddle version, the correct one is: http://jsfiddle.net/fcvyL/2/

Comment: Thank you so much, I see what you did now. It's much more clear now that I see it in the Fiddle.  So the validation part works now but now the limiter has been removed and no longer stops the user from typing anything which I had before.